# Hide/Show Div on Radio Selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, radio-button

I would like to hide/show a div based on radio selction.

-On page load the div is hidden and radio "yes" is selected.

-If user selects radio "no" the div would appear.

-If the user then rechecks "yes" the div would hide again.

Could anyone show me how this would work?

The html:

```
<table width="450px" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tr>
    <td width="200px" style="padding-top:3px; padding-left:3px;"><strong>Deliver Immediately?</strong>
    <input type="radio" name="imm" id="delivernow" checked="true" />Yes
    <input type="radio" name="imm" id="deliverlater" />No
    </td>   
    <td width="140px">       
            <div name="datediv">
                <label for="date">Select date:</label>
                <input type="Text" id="date" maxlength="25" size="25"/>
                <img src="images/cal.gif" onclick="javascript:NewCssCal('date','ddMMyyyy','arrow',true,'12','','future')" style="cursor:pointer"/>
            </div>
    </td>       
    </tr>
</table
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this? You will need to have jQuery loaded.

```
$(function(){
    $("div[name='datediv']").hide();
    $("#delivernow").add("#deliverlater").change(function(){
        $("div[name='datediv']").fadeToggle();
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery makes this fairly simple. You could add a click function to the radio group (in this case select using the name "**imm**") and check the id of the radio button that's been clicked like this:

```
$("input[name='imm']").click(function(){
    if($(this).attr("id") == "deliverlater"){
        $("#datediv").show();
    }else{
        $("#datediv").hide();   
    }
});
```

Here's a live example on jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/h9H29/

**EDIT:** Here's jQuery include code for you

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    // We place your page code here
    $("input[name='imm']").click(function(){
        if($(this).attr("id") == "deliverlater"){
            $("#datediv").show();
        }else{
            $("#datediv").hide();   
        }
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: This works nicely on jsfiddle but not on my website. 

JQuery must not be loaded?? I put the script from jsfiddle in <script></script> within my page header?

Comment: Yeah if you make sure jQuery is included that should sort it. Do you have any errors? Common error for jQuery not included/loaded is "$ is not defined".

Comment: @BrettJMason I've added the jQuery include for you now dude. Should just be able to copy it in :)